# inefficient SQL plan on the partitioned Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

we are facing issue with one of query which joins between few tables.
even though there are few hundreds of records in the table the plan is going to Merge join thinking only one record in the table, please find the below plan. 
when the Merge sort plan is used the query fails with temp space issue.

oracle choose Merge plan only when job loaded to newly created partition. but the rest of old partitions it is choosing Hash Join where we get results in few seconds.

for information. All the joined table has same volume.

could you please explain why this is happening?

```
Merg join( query hung)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                                                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                               |     1 |   712 |    36   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                  |                               |     1 |   712 |    36   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN      |                               |     1 |   679 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN     |                               |     1 |   615 |    21   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                
|   4 |     MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN    |                               |     1 |   388 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                
|   5 |      PARTITION RANGE SINGLE |                               |     1 |   105 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL     | PCA_DCM_CLNT_BSPKE_REFS_M_LND |     1 |   105 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|   7 |      BUFFER SORT            |                               |     1 |   283 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                
|   8 |       PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                               |     1 |   283 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|*  9 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PCA_DCM_INDBTDNS_BLK_M_LND    |     1 |   283 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|  10 |     BUFFER SORT             |                               |     1 |   227 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                
|  11 |      PARTITION RANGE SINGLE |                               |     1 |   227 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|* 12 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL     | PCA_DCM_DELPHI_BLK_M_LND      |     1 |   227 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|  13 |    BUFFER SORT              |                               |     1 |    64 |    21   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                
|  14 |     PARTITION RANGE SINGLE  |                               |     1 |    64 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|* 15 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL      | PCA_DCM_APACS_BLK_M_LND       |     1 |    64 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|  16 |   PARTITION RANGE SINGLE    |                               |     1 |    33 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
|* 17 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL        | PCA_DCM_SCORE_BLK_M_LND       |     1 |    33 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hash join(Few seconds we get the results)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                 
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                               |   491 |   341K|    74   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                 |                               |   491 |   341K|    74   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE SINGLE   |                               |   493 |   109K|    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | PCA_DCM_DELPHI_BLK_M_LND      |   493 |   109K|    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  4 |   HASH JOIN                |                               |   491 |   232K|    60   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  5 |    HASH JOIN               |                               |   492 | 99384 |    45   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  6 |     HASH JOIN              |                               |   492 | 47724 |    31   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   7 |      PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                               |   493 | 16269 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  8 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PCA_DCM_SCORE_BLK_M_LND       |   493 | 16269 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   9 |      PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                               |   493 | 31552 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|* 10 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PCA_DCM_APACS_BLK_M_LND       |   493 | 31552 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|  11 |     PARTITION RANGE SINGLE |                               |   493 | 51765 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|* 12 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL     | PCA_DCM_CLNT_BSPKE_REFS_M_LND |   493 | 51765 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|  13 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE  |                               |   493 |   136K|    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
|* 14 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | PCA_DCM_INDBTDNS_BLK_M_LND    |   493 |   136K|    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please find the query

```
SELECT
substr(BLK.ACC_NUM,1,14) AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
CASE WHEN SUBSTR(BLK.ACC_NUM,20,1) = '1'   THEN 'F1'  
        WHEN SUBSTR(BLK.ACC_NUM,20,1) = ' '   THEN 'F1'  
        WHEN SUBSTR(BLK.ACC_NUM,20,1) = '0'   THEN 'F1'  
         WHEN SUBSTR(BLK.ACC_NUM,20,1) = '2'   THEN 'F2'
   END FLTR,
DELPHI.ND_SPA_CII_SPA
FROM
BUR_LND.PCA_DCM_SCORE_BLK_M_LND BLK
INNER JOIN BUR_LND.PCA_DCM_CLNT_BSPKE_REFS_M_LND REFFS
ON BLK.ACC_NUM= REFFS.ACC_NUM
INNER JOIN BUR_LND.PCA_DCM_INDBTDNS_BLK_M_LND IND
ON BLK.ACC_NUM= IND.ACC_NUM
INNER JOIN BUR_LND.PCA_DCM_DELPHI_BLK_M_LND DELPHI
ON BLK.ACC_NUM= DELPHI.ACC_NUM
INNER JOIN BUR_LND.PCA_DCM_APACS_BLK_M_LND APACS
ON BLK.ACC_NUM= APACS.ACC_NUM
WHERE 
BLK.EFF_DT=TO_DATE('2013-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND REFFS.EFF_DT=TO_DATE('2013-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND IND.EFF_DT=TO_DATE('2013-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND DELPHI.EFF_DT=TO_DATE('2013-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND APACS.EFF_DT=TO_DATE('2013-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Thanks
arkesh

Comment: Perhaps statistics have not yet been collected on the newly created partitions? Check the column `LAST_ANALYZED` on the `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS` catalog view.

Comment: I have added the query.  about the Stats Gather.No we have not collected the stats in between. the Flow is  Create partition --> Load Data --> Select Data(this is part job failing). all this happens in one Flow/job.

Answer (score 1):

The plans are bad because the new partition is missing statistics.  Statistics should be updated after partition changes, ideally using incremental statistics.  If that's not possible then a hint like `/*+ dynamic_sampling(4) */` can help.

Statistics can be accurate, inaccurate, or missing.  Missing statistics are generally not a huge problem because of dynamic sampling.  With the default dynamic sampling level, 2, Oracle will automatically gather statistics if a statement includes tables without statistics.

Unfortunately for this case, Oracle only considers missing statistics per *table*, not per *partition*.  (That would be a good feature request, but that won't help you right now.)  With the literals in the SQL statement Oracle appears to know exactly which partition to look in.  Since there are no statistics for that partition it assumes there are no rows, leading to the bad plans.

**Example**

Create a sample partitioned table with 1000 rows but no gathered statistics.

```
create table partition_test
(
    a number,
    b number
)
partition by range (a)
(
    partition p1 values less than (2)
);
insert into partition_test select 1, level from dual connect by level <= 1000;
```

When there are no statistics Oracle will use dynamic sampling automatically and get a good row count.  You can't see it in this simple plan, but normally this would lead to better access methods and better join operations.

```
explain plan for select * from partition_test where a = 1 and b <= 1000;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 4097357352
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                |  1000 | 26000 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                |  1000 | 26000 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PARTITION_TEST |  1000 | 26000 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("A"=1 AND "B"<=1000)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Gather stats, then create a new partition with data.  Although that partition has 1000 rows and no stats, Oracle does not know that and just assumes it's empty.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'partition_test');
end;
/
alter table partition_test add partition p2 values less than (3);
insert into partition_test select 2, level from dual connect by level <= 1000;
explain plan for select * from partition_test where a = 2 and b <= 1000;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 4097357352

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                |     1 |     7 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                |     1 |     7 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PARTITION_TEST |     1 |     7 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("A"=2 AND "B"<=1000)
```

Explicitly requesting dynamic sampling will fix the cardinality estimates, which would likely solve your execution plan problems.

```
explain plan for select /*+ dynamic_sampling(4) */ * from partition_test where a = 2 and b <= 1000;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 4097357352

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                |  1000 |  7000 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                |  1000 |  7000 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PARTITION_TEST |  1000 |  7000 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("A"=2 AND "B"<=1000)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=4)
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.I was on holiday. Thanks for your Answer, it helped  understand in deep.  Now we are looking into few jobs to change the approach